# How does the My Verizon Mobile app know the device phone number?

Tags: ios

I just installed the My Verizon Mobile app onto an iPhone and upon launch it was immediately able to display the device's phone number - something which is not possible for regular apps to do.

Does anybody know how it does it, could it be one of these, or something else?

- As the app is from Verizon, Apple has granted it permission to access private iOS APIs to obtain the phone number
- The App makes an HTTP connection to a Verizon server which goes through a gateway which is able to detect the phone number and sends it back to the device in the HTTP response.

These are just my guesses as to what perhaps could be happening, does anybody know what actually is happening?

Comment: My own theory involves black helicopters.

Comment: I just installed the My Verizon app on 2 different Verizon iPhone 5s, and the app's login screen displayed neither phone's phone number. Is your experience repeatable?

Comment: Probably the phone store does something to set the number into the phone, in a way that the app can access it.

Comment: @John Sauer - yes it is

Comment: @Hot Licks. I would be very surprised at that.What and how do you think a store is setting something that the app could access. And if this app can access it then what is to stop other apps from accessing it also?

Comment: @John - turn off your wifi, if it makes a wifi connection it prompts for un/pw. If it makes a connection over the phone network it doesn't. Hence I think the MDN is being injected at the gateway

Comment: We're both talking about [My Verizon Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-verizon-mobile/id416023011?mt=8), right? I uninstalled the app, turned off my iPhone's Wi-Fi, downloaded the app over Verizon LTE, and launched it; yet still [I do not see my iPhone's number displayed.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QYi0T.png)

Comment: Yes that's the app. My network indicator in the status bar says 3G however not LTE. It must only work for particular gateways.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Settings/General/About, you'll find an IMEI number and an ICCID number. The IMEI number identifies the phone, the ICCID number identifies the SIM card. If you have a Verizon phone account, then Verizon would have associated that ICCID number with a phone number. They *must* be able to do that, because otherwise how could Verizon ring your phone if I dial your number?

So what happens is Verizon using their own data, which they *must* have for your phone to function properly, to find the phone number associated with your SIM card. This should only work for Verizon phones (other phone companies should be able to find your phone number if you have a contract with them, but not if you are with Verizon).

By the way, if you go to Settings/Phone, the first thing my iPhone shows is "My Number".

Comment: Of course the phone network has access to the IMEI and ICCID and phone number, but how can the iOS app get access to that association and "their own data" is my question. Which still isn't answered. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

The Verizon Mobile app, at least for android, carries special code apps in the rom.   You cna verify this by taking a Verizon Galaxy Nexus and applying an alternate rom to it such as CM10.   Without the special "carrier blobs" in the rom, Verizon "specialized apps", don't work.

This is not a bug per se -- non Verizon roms lack the special "carrier bits" but also like the carrier apps many people don't want on their Nexi.  The reason you have no "auto login" on iPhones is because this carrier "app" doesn't exist in the Apple roms.

Comment: Thanks, but what has this got to do with the question? I asked how the app knows the device phone number. Your answer doesn't even touch on that. The app is not in the rom yet it is still able to detect the phone number of the device.